# How to retrieve a Google Sheet in a Browser Extension with a JS fetch() call?

Tags: javascript, fetch, google-sheets-api, browser-extension, manifest.json

So I have been doing several hours of searching on this and cannot find anything that works with the current Google Sheets API (v4) in a browser. I can 100% get data through Postman and even a browser address bar. I have a public Google Spreadsheet. I have an API Key. I can successfully return all of the row data.

As soon as I try to do so in a browser extension, I get nothing.

Is anyone aware of how to configure a JavaScript fetch() call to get a successful return on a public Google Spreadsheet? No editing, no deleting. Just a GET.

Here's what I'm trying but isn't working:

```js
var url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/${sheetId}?key=${key}`

var response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "no-cors",
        headers: {
            "Host": "sheets.googleapis.com"
        }
    });
```

Two things I noticed:

1. If `mode` wasn't set to `no-cors` in the `fetch()` I would get a NetworkError
2. In Postman if there wasn't a `Host` header, I would get an error response

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get may help.

Comment: No. It does not. I used the Google documentation to construct the call in the first place. As I said: it works in a browser address bar and it works in Postman. I need to know how to get it to work in a fetch() call. I also stated I am working in a browser extension. I do not have the same ease of access of including things like external libraries like `gapi`.

Comment: In your script, when your values of `spreadsheetId`, `sheetId` and `key` are the valid values, when `console.log(await fetch(url).then(r => r.json()))` is used instead of your fetch script of `var response = await fetch(url, {,,,`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike
`
Response
​
body: null
​
bodyUsed: false
​
headers: Headers {  }
​
ok: false
​
redirected: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: ""
​
type: "opaque"
​
url: ""
`

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I think that your Spreadsheet doesn't correctly return the value. Because when I tested it using a sample publicly shared Spreadsheet, I can confirm that the correct value is returned. I apologize for this. So I'm worry that the values of `spreadsheetId`, `sheetId` and `key` might be invalid. How about this? For example, when your sample Spreadsheet is publicly shared, can you provide the sample URL you are using without  the api key?

Comment: *sigh* I have already said that I can get a valid response with data in Postman or a Browser. Which would mean, the variable data I need to provide to Google in the API call is valid. Do you have a working fetch statement? That is the part I am looking for. If you tested in a browser or in Postman, then this won't help me if yours also fails in a fetch statement. Here is the ID `1EctCVQqIuc2WhOTGjUqBzNcRCEWXBXUyHxXJSUIP3P8` and here is the sheet `Sheet1`. If you have a fetch statement that worked, that's all I need. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. In my environment, I could confirm that the following script returns correctly the values from your Spreadsheet. `console.log(await fetch("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1EctCVQqIuc2WhOTGjUqBzNcRCEWXBXUyHxXJSUIP3P8/values/Sheet1?key={Your API KEY}").then(r => r.json()))` Can you confirm whether the URL is the same with your URL, and test it again?

Comment: OK, so I guess it's my fault I didn't try this earlier, but it didn't cross my mind there might be some sort of restriction, but it seems like because I am calling this in a Browser Extension, the behavior is different. I decided to try this in a simple index.html and JS file, and it works. So there must be something about doing this in a Browser Extension that is getting in the way. This is really frustrating.

Comment: So it is most definitely a restriction because of being a Browser Extension. Fetch is restricted. Apparently setting a host permission should fix it, but I am still getting the same result, but I am also not sure if just `*://localhost/*` is a good enough permission or not. It hasn't seemed to change anything yet. But at least there is finally progressive after countless hours of digging around online...lol.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for the help. I was able to get a little more focused through your results and figured out what I had to do. I have posted my answer below. I upvoted your comments if it helps at all...lol.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind this is an issue that specifically has to do with writing Browser Extensions/Addons, not just the typical `fetch()` usage in a browser.

To resolve this, I had to add a host permission in the `manifest.json` file to allow the URL for the Google API `sheets.googleapis.com` I am calling, like this:

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Browser Extension",
    "description": "description",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {
        "64": "icons/icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background_script.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "*://sheets.googleapis.com/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
    [...]
```

As far as the fetch call, all I need is the URL. No need for any options to be set.